# Any top-bottom layout in networkx?

Tags: python-3.x, networking, layout, directed-acyclic-graphs

I would like to display rather big directed acyclic graph with [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/), but most layouts look like for small symmetric graphs. Are threre any top-to-bottom or left-to-right layouts like this

[image]